# Should we prevent filters with empty names?

Tags: bug, status-completed, custom-questions-list

As you can see in the screencast below I can create as many filters with whitespace characters only as I want. Is this by design or should it be raised as a bug?

[image]

Once another filter is active, all whitespace characters only filters become inaccessible. You can't click on them from the dropdown menu and you cannot edit them anymore from the "Saved Filters" box.

[image]

It is also possible to create filters with names that look the same: *(just prepend or append some whitespaces to the name)*

[image]

Comment: How do i filter, i don't even have the "more" dropdown.

Comment: @U9-Forward I believe it's the "Custom Question Lists" option on [your profile's Preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/8708364).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that filter doesn't even work terribly well. Does it filter out anything?

Comment: There is always one input box which is not sanitised somewhere in a site.

Comment: If you want to enable it, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

Comment: This isn't quite so big of an issue as it might be on an email service or something...I doubt anyone would hack your SE account in order to stealthily ensure you don't answer questions before them.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I'm not entirely sure what your point is. I'm not concerned with security but more about the user experience. The current implementation seems to assume that people don't make mistake. As I have demonstrated it, you can potentially create a filter with an empty name and never be able to correct it. While this isn't a security flaw it seems wrong from a user experience point of view.

Comment: @customcommander Ah, well, that's what my first thought is in these sorts of matters.

Comment: Leading whitespace in filters seems like an unuseful feature. Trailing whitespace as well.

Comment: i was trying to test if these ghost named filters could be accessed using keyboard navigation.. but this bug seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @ocæon Yep, it looks like they rolled out a fix. Thanks for letting me know, I'll mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should we prevent filters with empty names?

The answer seems to be **Yes** as the issue has been fixed now.

[image]

Comment: trimming input goes a long way.